# Revoking Android Native App Access Token from WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: android, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I was testing the SSO for Native Mobile App(http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/sso-for-native-mobile-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/) that incoporate with WSO2 Identity Server. Everything went fine according to the guide but one problem that I encounter is there is no method of how to revoke the access token through Android when I sign-off / logout from the app. Therefore, I would to ask for some guide/help on writting a working method/code in revoking/removing the access token from the Android App.

Comment: Its unwise, but do you have a working set where the sample works; i am trying to develope a app for wso2 IS sso using oauth2 referring to above sample; but couldn't follow. so can you provide me a sample if you have developed

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is to revoke the access token at IS server side, from the android app. In that case following guide will help you. You can make a REST call to the server in the given manner to revoke a token.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/OAuth2+Token+Revocation